# In jquery sortable UI,What can we get from the event function's parameters like ui and event?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I know we can get the current dragged element's `id` by `ui.item.attr('id')`

but what can we get from `event` parameter? Could it like javascript, have `event.target` property?

or get anything else?

Answer (score 1):

All callbacks receive two arguments: The original browser event and a prepared ui object, view below (if you name your second argument 'ui'), you can do:

**ui.helper** - the current helper element (most often a clone of the item)
**ui.position** - current position of the helper
**ui.offset** - current absolute position of the helper
**ui.item** - the current dragged element
**ui.placeholder** - the placeholder (if you defined one)
**ui.sender** - the sortable where the item comes from (only exists if you move from one connected list to another)

You can also get this info from the UI documentation. http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the object in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome's Dev tools to see what information it provides.

Here's what I get in the `stop` event:

[image]

And if you expand the `originalEvent: a.Event` node, there's the `target` that you are looking for: `target: HTMLTableCellElement`